# NullPointerExecption

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I made a simple function:

```
public class AjouterBouton {

    public AjouterBouton(int nombre) {

        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[nombre];

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            buttons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            JPanel pan = Main.grille;
            pan.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

"grille" is a simple JPanel in my Main Class:

```
JPanel grille = new JPanel();
int ligne = 6;
int colone = 5;
grille.setBounds(6, 117, 980, 314);
grille.setLayout(new GridLayout(ligne,colone));
```

and finally, I added this into the Main class:

```
new AjouterBouton(72);
```

However, I get a `JavaNullPointerException`.

**PS**: I tried this, which works:

```
final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[72];

for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    buttons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    grille.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

But I want to add my button using the method. I'm a beginner; can someone help me?

Comment: Always add the stacktrace with your question, which indicates the line where the error is thrown.

Comment: And please get rid of the "stuck 2 hours" bit. How does that help us figure out your problem? What is its relevance to the problem -- none. The key when asking questions like this is to include *relevant* information pertaining to the problem, like the stacktrace and the line that causes it, and leaving out irrelevant bits that only serve to distract.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and with the tag we know that is `JAVA`

Comment: `JPanel pan = Main.grille;` this is not necessary at all..

Comment: At what point do you actually utilize pan?  You use it to make a copy of grille, but don't show where you actually use it.  That's where you're getting the error, because pan only exists inside the for loop

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels should be `NullPointerException` but already exist :P

Comment: @nachokk I use grille because i want to add my buttons in this JPanel ;)

Comment: As I see, your `grille` is a static field of class Main, right (since I see no Main variable, so it's a class)? And if you initialize `grille` in class Main's constructor as a local variable `JPanel grille = new JPanel();` then of course `Main.grille` is a NullReference. You'd get 2 `grille`: local variable `grille` and static field `grille` of class Main where only the local one is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference of the JPanel to your constructor method:

```
public AjouterBouton(int nombre, JPanel pan)
{
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[nombre];

    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        buttons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        //JPanel pan = Main.grille;
        pan.add(buttons[i]);
    }
}
```

In Main:

```
int ligne = 6;
int colone = 5;

JPanel grille = new JPanel();
grille.setBounds(6, 117, 980, 314);
grille.setLayout(new GridLayout(ligne,colone));
// this could be just a static method call: AddButtonsToPanel()
// doesn't need to be an object
AjouterBouton button = new AjouterBouton(72, grille);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JPanel pan = Main.grille;
```

That line of code is called within the `for` loop in the `AjouterBouton` method.  It is disposed of when the method exists.

Without seeing the stack trace, I'd have to go out on a limb and say you're getting the `NullPointerException` because you're trying to add `pan` to your panel when it hasn't been instantiated properly.

Comment: Now I've an other problem I got ArrayIndexOufOfBoundsExecption. In my method : new AjouterBouton(3); i get this error .. could you help me please?

Comment: Sure, post up another question with code and the stack trace, I'll be happy to help